# Setting a variable to the result of a select query SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find the most economical way of achieving a way to return the data I want and also updating another table within the same Stored Procedure.

I have drastically simplified my SQL below to illustrate my issue.
Here's what I want to achieve :

```
DECLARE @UserID INT
SELECT TOP(1) @UserID = UserID, UserName, email, (#Loads of other columns#) FROM Users
UPDATE Logins SET LoggedIn = 1 WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

I understand I could do this by making sure that all returned columns are assigned to a local variable, but there are too many to be an efficient SPROC.

I don't want to have to do the SELECT statement twice (once to return the data and once to set the variable, ready for the update statement)

Any suggestions guys ?
Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Do you mean economical as in server performance or as in shorter, neater code?

Comment: A bit of both I guess, maybe just what you would consider to be the "best" way.
This SPROC is likely to be hit several thousand times per day...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OUTPUT` to get values to a local table variable but you still have to use a local `SELECT` to get a single value from the table variable.

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(userid int, username varchar(50), email varchar(50), logged bit)

DECLARE @userid int

UPDATE TOP (1) Users
SET logged = 1
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO @TBL

SELECT top (1) @userid = userid from @TBL

SELECT @userid
```

[Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/778a6/4/0)

Comment: From a server performance point of view - Do you think creating a temporary table would be more efficient than either creating lots of variables or just making 2 select statements ?

Comment: Not sure how it would effect local performance, but it would only need to open a single transaction which would be a bonus, I guess it would decrease reads but increase cpu load slightly. Not got a machine available I can test it with sadly.